# Writing pandas df to sql dB with a new column not working with append

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

trying to do some self-learning with pandas/ sql alchemy. I've set up a dummy dB ms SQL 2012 (dB we use at work) on my local system and I can

read data from it

create a table from an existing dB to it (tested up to 5 million rows of ints and short strings which took about 9 minutes)

update it with and append new rows

replace all target rows with `df with if_exists='replace'`

now what I can't figure out, and this is probably due to my ignorance is how to write a dataframe with an additional column into my dB.

take the following df which I would pull from my dB

```
   stores = np.random.choice(800,5,replace=True)
week1 = np.random.randint(1,500,size=5)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Stores' : stores,'Week 1' : week1})
    print(df)
    Stores  Week 1
0   461 413
1   568 181
2   793 173
3   349 49
4   713 258
```

now if I wanted to update this with the existing columns and new rows this works perfectly as expected, but if I create a new column :

```
df['Week 2'] = np.random.randint(1,500,size=len(df))
```

I get the following error when using :

```
df.to_sql(name='my table',
con = engine,
index=False,
if_exists='append')



    ProgrammingError: ('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'Week 2'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S22] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'Week 2'. (207); [42S22] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

any help/documentation guidance is greatly appreciated as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in error description, "Week 2" is unacceptable name of table column in Mysql **"Invalid column name 'Week 2'."**,

ProgrammingError: ('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]**Invalid column name 'Week 2'**. (207) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S22] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]**Invalid column name '1956'.** (207); [42S22] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

Change it to (for example) **Week2** and it should work properly.

```
df['Week2'] = np.random.randint(1,500,size=len(df))
```

Also it sees "1956" as column name but I don't know if it's because of previous error or not so please correct this one first ;)

Comment: ah my apologies, i was trying to replicate the data I have at work 1956 = FY 19 Week 56 but changed it Week 1/2 to make it more understandable. I will test using a string name but the column name I used initially was 1956 and the dtype is set to an object.

Comment: I think problem lays in whitespaces in column names. Names like this are not acceptable by MySQL as errors shows, so try to remove them and use **Week_1** or **Week1** name conventions

Comment: just tried this and it failed again - ProgrammingError: ('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'Week56'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S22] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'Week56'. (207); [42S22] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

Comment: Weirdly, if I use if_exists='replace' it replaces the entire table so I don't think it's a case of the name?

Comment: It had problem with existing database scheme, because it tried to depend on it. When you did **if_exists='replace'** you're forced new scheme so if there is no problem now... then it;s not about name and you're right.

Comment: Damian, you were right, it was the column name. Basically, I created my column name '1956' as a string but SQL reads the column header as an int(!?) so creating a new column as a string was throwing the error. Just tested with 9 different columns. Thanks so much. you are the man.